# Catch unity game crash for others

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Problem: my game has no errors for me, but have crashes for some others.
Question: has any reason to catch crashes(not errors) and exist way to catch this?
For example i use this for tests.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Diagnostics;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TestDiag : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Text _text;
    void OnEnable() { Application.logMessageReceived += Log; }
     
    void OnDisable() { Application.logMessageReceived -= Log; }
     
    public void Log(string logString, string stackTrace, LogType type)
    {
            //SEND MAIL
    }

    //Make null error - its working and send report
    public void NullErrorButton()
    {
        _text.text = "null";
    }
    
    //Make crash game - its crash game - not send anything!
    public void CrashGameButton()
    {
        Utils.ForceCrash(ForcedCrashCategory.Abort);
    }
}
```

Problem here - its crash game, but log not catch anything.

Comment: Have you checked the player log file anyway?

Comment: unity editor log ?

Comment: player log contains crash @derHugo

Comment: Its windows app. @TimChang

Comment: So yeah in general .. if an app crashes .. how do you expect it to still execute code such as sending an email? ;) Usually you do these kind of things by e.g. having a complete separate background process (Unity e.g. has a `UnityCrashHandler` running along with the Editor itself) .. then you either kill the connection clean or you know that the main process unexpectedly stopped working/responding => then you fetch the log file and send a crash report via that secondary process

Comment: uhh, maybe on app start i need check previous Player-prev.log file, if it contains crash data, then send this file data. But not sure, what game print if it crash. @derHugo